# Без докера микросервис запускается, а с докером нет (ошибка подключения к порту)

Tags: postgresql, docker

У меня такая проблема. Создал пустой микросервис, сделал миграцию для него через Liquibase (БД Postgres), добавил докер (файлы Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml). В результате, если просто запустить микросервис через IntelliJ IDEA, то нормально запускается, если же запускать в контейнере докера, то ошибка "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего может быть эта ошибка? Как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь подключиться к "localhost". В Docker контейнере требуется подключаться по имени службы [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).
Каждый контейнер доступен для обнаружения по имени службы.

Попробуйте указать имя контейнера postgres и подключиться postgres:5432

Comment: Мне вчера подсказали на другом форуме, что хороший вариант - запускать базу данных в отдельном контейнере. Так и сделал, всё работает. Вы, похоже, то же самое предлагали.

Comment: Вообще это хорошая практика , использовать для одного сервиса - один контейнер. А не стараться запихнуть всё в один контейнер, это уже какая то виртуальная машина получается.